# Enumeration of array returning custom object and not string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, enumerator

I am having an issue retrieving a `NSString` from an array, instead of the string, I get back the object that the string is inside of. This is the structure I have.

`NSMuteableArray` > ArrayOfObjects > `NSString` (this string is in each object in the Array of objects).

I am trying to assign the string to a cell in a tableview, but for now I just want to log out the correct data. Here is the code that I am trying, again it works, but instead of the string, I get back the parent object.

```
for (NSString *amountOwed in [[[dataSingelton mutableDataArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]personsBillsArray])
{
    NSLog(@"the value owed is %@", amountOwed);
}
```

Each object  inside of `personsBillsArray` has a property of `amountOwed`.

Comment: for (id object in [[[dataSingelton mutableDataArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]personsBillsArray]) and use in nslog to get date rom object like this NSLog(@"the value owed is %@", object .amountOwed);

Answer (score 2):

You're close:

```
NSArray *array = [[[dataSingelton mutableDataArray] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] personsBillsArray];
for (id obj in array)
{
    NSString *amountOwed = [obj amountOwed];
    NSLog(@"the value owed is %@", amountOwed);
}
```